# Show downvotes on reputation "post" even when suspended

Tags: bug, profile-page, account-suspension, reputation-history

I noticed this week: when you are suspended, the "reputation post" only shows upvotes:

[image: upvotes]

Only when the suspension has ended, you can see that also downvotes occured:

[image: all-votes]

Sure, just a minor thing, but simply: an unnecessary inconsistency. That overview could either show "no votes" at all, or "all votes".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does show the vote, it just doesn't record a reputation loss because at the time it was cast, their reputation was 1 and could not go any lower.

Users receive a reputation recalculation shortly after their suspension which is what restores their reputation to its correct value. It also restores reputation loss for downvotes or any other inconsistencies that might have arisen due to the suspension.

Without calculating the true value of their reputation on every downvote, there isn't any way of knowing whether the new downvote would actually cause a reputation loss or not at the time it's cast. It's a lot easier and more performance friendly to just look at their current reputation and let it get fixed later.

Comment: That makes total sense ;-)

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica much like the opposite situation, where you reach the daily maximum, the one vote *pinning* you to 200 is often less than 10 and subsequent votes are blank or unrecorded.

Comment: @Rob Subsequent **up**votes that is. Downvotes still kick in. I had more than one day on MSE where it showed +200 before going to bed, and +198 or +196 the next morning, albeit there were plenty of upvotes prior to those two final downvotes before the "new day begins".

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica, that's because you *can* go down, when at 1 rep you can't and the "1 hour ago" or "17:41" is blank (until you are unsuspend, unlike being pinned (where the *rule* isn't relaxed), not including the pinning exceptions).

Comment: @Rob I agree for the "suspension" counters, but for the daily cap limit, one could also compute the overall, final number *per* day simply by throwing together all events of that day. So that you dont end up +198 when you got 50 upvotes that day, and only one downvote.

Comment: TIL that suspended accounts can gain & lose rep. So it's not a waste to vote on their posts.